# XCode 12.3 - Handle REST Api Response

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, rest

As I am new to Stack Overflow , I apologize in case my question is not formulated well.

Here is my problem, I've been stuck now for some time trying to handle my JSON REST API response.

**I need help for:**

**Problem 1:** I want my GameView to display all Game Categories (See [Problem1] in Source code)

**Problem 2:** General guidance, I'm fairly new to Swift, is that the right approach or general considered "bad style"? ([Problem 2])

**Problem3:** How do I properly call another View, after successful login

These are shortened Versions of my Files:

Api.swift:

```
class Api {
    
    struct category {
        var title: String
        var id: Int
    }
    
    // [Problem 2] using static var? feels like bad practice but works 
    public static var categories: [category] // = [category(title:"Spielfilme",id:2)]

    func login(name: String, pass:String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let params = ["action":"auth","name":name, "pass":pass] as Dictionary<String, String>
        call_api(params:params) { result in
            // [Problem1] this is how i would do in javascript, I've heared of 'unwrap' function in swift?
            // for (category, index) in result["categories"] {
            //     categories[] = category(title:category.title, id: category.id)
            // }
            completion()

            // [Problem3] I would need to call / display GameView() somehow, either here ...
        }
    }

...
```

LoginView.swift:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var is_logged_in = false
    var body: some View {
        if(!is_logged_in) {
             ...
             Button("Create Account or Login") {
                  Api.login( ... , completion: () {
                       // [Problem3] this is how I do it right now
                       is_logged_in=true
                  }
             }
             ...
        } else { GameView() }
...
```

GameView.swift:

```
...
struct GameView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // [Problem 2]
            ForEach(Api.categories, id: \.self) { category in
                CategoryCard(category.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is probably a bit too broad for this site. You are right, that a static property isn't the best approach. You typically use code the completion handler to process the fetched data.  The network code isn't responsible for updating views. Again, you would typically do this in the completion handler code (which may well come from your view). Introducing SwiftUI changes it a bit because it can react to changes in your model. I suggest you work through this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui

Comment: Or Google "swiftui rest tutorial" for others